# Is Sitecore Claims Aware?

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6, adfs

We'd like to use ADFS with our Sitecore (6.4) solution to validate users. We have an ADFS Proxy in our DMZ and an ADFS Server in our company domain, our Sitecore solution is hosted for us elsewhere.

We've been told that if Sitecore is fully claims aware (i.e. can consume federation claims without requiring a Windows Logon session) then this basic infrastructure is enough.

If Sitecore isn't fully claims aware then we'll need to establish an external domain, with domain controller and Federation server at our Sitecore host.

So, is Sitecore fully claims aware?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's unlikely that you'll get it out of the box. Check out the recent blog entry about Sitecore and Windows Identity Foundation here: http://webcmd.wordpress.com/2012/07/09/federated-authentication-with-sitecore-and-the-windows-identity-foundation/

Comment: The code is on Sitecore's Shared Source site: http://trac.sitecore.net/FedAuthenticator